# Unexpected output for counts over time

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In the following query I get cumulative reps, and their respective clients overtime (at end of month):

```
select month, count(rep_id), sum(cliets) 
  from
( 
  select date_trunc('month', date)::date as month, rep_id, 
    row_number() over (PARTITION BY rep_id, date_trunc('month', date) order by date desc) as rnk,
    sum(case when applied_date <= date then 1 else 0 end) clients
  from
  ( 
    select r.rep_id, r.created_date, u.id as user_id, u.applied_date
    from reps r
    left outer join clients u on r.id = u.rep_id
  ) z
cross join
  (select * from calendar
    where date between '2018-01-01' and convert_timezone('PST', getdate())
  ) c
group by date, rep_id
) sub
where rnk=1
group by 1
```

This is the output:

```
month       count   sum
1/1/2018    1000    2000
2/1/2018    1000    3000
3/1/2018    1000    4000
```

Clients overtime are indeed correct, however, how can I get the correct counts for reps cumulatively like so:

```
month       count   sum
1/1/2018    350     2000
2/1/2018    700     3000
3/1/2018    1000    4000
```

FYI I can get this to work in Tableau by doing AGG(rep_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to fix in the query.

`count(rep_id)` is counting the non-NULL values, since there are probably no NULL rep_id, this is the same as counting the number of rows.

`group by date, rep_id` is returning 1 row per rep_id AND per date not per month. I understand you need to group by date because you use it in the row_number() function.

Without modifying too much of the original query I would write it this way: (sorry not tested)

```
select month, count(DISTINCT rep_id), count(DISTINCT user_id) 
  from
( 
  select date_trunc('month', date)::date as month, 
    CASE WHEN created_date <= date THEN rep_id ELSE NULL END rep_id, 
    case when applied_date <= date then user_id else null end) user_id
  from
  ( 
    select r.rep_id, r.created_date, u.id as user_id, u.applied_date
    from reps r
    left outer join clients u on r.id = u.rep_id
  ) z
cross join
  (select * from calendar
    where date between '2018-01-01' and convert_timezone('PST', getdate())
  ) c
) sub
group by 1
```

This:

```
   CASE WHEN created_date <= date THEN rep_id ELSE NULL END rep_id, 
    case when applied_date <= date then user_id else null end) user_id
```

returns the rep_id or user_id when it was seen before the date.

Then

```
count(DISTINCT rep_id), count(DISTINCT user_id)
```

counts how many there were in or before the month.

Comment: Hi Ghislain and welcome. Try to take the StackOverflow's [tour] and how to provide a [mcve]